# momentary push switch triggering twice

Tags: switches, floating-pin

I have a momentary push switch connected to my mbed microcontroller. The switch is used to trigger an interrupt which changes a setting on the device. 
[image]

At the moment the button works around 70% of the time. But every now and again when I press it it triggers the interrupt twice?

Is this a problem with my code or do I have a floating switch? And how would I fix it?

I have tried changing the resistor (I initially had 1K and it worked even less of the time)

Thanks!

Comment: In the code running on your micro, do consider contact bounce ? For example see: http://www.elexp.com/contact_bounce_and_debounce.aspx Also, a 100 ohm for the resistor is wasting too much power, I would use at least 10 k ohm. With proper debouncing in software this will work flawlessly.

Comment: Useful search term : "switch debouncing".

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @FakeMoustache for the link and Brian for the search term. Works perfectly now. +1's all around!